# error Failed to install the app. Couldn't find "DevDebug" build variant. Available variants are:

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

I upgraded react-native version 0.64.4 to latest (0.73.2) of react native application. package (npm i ) successfully installed but . when run my app **npm run android-dev** than i found that error.
**[image: error Failed to install the app. Couldn't find "DevDebug" build variant. Available variants are: .]**